# How to manipulate the camera in Fortnite Creative and Battle Lab?

Tags: ps4, fortnite-battle-royale

So, I've seen the Fortography challenge results now and then and it's left me wondering exactly how these people take these pictures since I can't find any camera tools in Creative or Battle Lab. The closest thing I've managed thus far is placing my character close enough to an object that it forces the camera into first person, but that only works if there is a large enough object around and it returns to third person as soon as I move. There has to be some way since people are clearly doing it. So, my question is, how do you manipulate the camera in these modes to change the viewing angle or go into first person to get better pictures and video?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the best way to take a good picture would be to use the Replay mode

So go in a game, and place yourself how you want to be seen in your photo. Then complete that game (killing yourself is fine)

Then load the game in the Replay mode, and that should give you the possibility to enter freecam mode. Where you can put the camera whereever you want.

So that should give you the possibility to take any shot you want, without having to fuss around to figure how to get the shot in the middle of a game where you get shot.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and that seems like it would work, but there's one problem. The tutorial is for PC. I need to know how to do this on PS4, which I included in the question's tags. I don't have any idea what the guy is talking about when it comes to controls and buttons since they're completely different.

Comment: Usually, all controls should be on the HUD. It should be quite easy to figure out.